# How to set different versions for Android and iOS apps in single config.xml (PhoneGap Build)?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

My app uses 4-digits version numbers like this: "1.8.3.2". It's ok for Android, but App Store for iOS supports only 3-digits version numbers.

So, I need to set "1.8.3.2" for Android and "1.8.32" for iOS. How I can do this in single config.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this, some post build editing of the generated manifest files is needed (`AndroidManifest.xml` and `<app>-Info.plist` for Android and iOS respectively).

This can be automated with the [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) plugin. First add the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config
```

Then add the following to your `config.xml`:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-manifest/@android:versionName" value="1.8.3.2" />
    ...
</platform>
...
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="CFBundleShortVersionString" target="*-Info.plist" mode="replace"> 
        <string>1.8.32</string>
    </config-file>
    ...
</platform>
```

Comment: As I understand `android-versionCode` and `ios-CFBundleVersion` are package numbers, not versions of app. This values are not displayed in the store for customers.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I edited the answer with another solution (hopefully the correct one ;-) )

Comment: thanks. Also, is there a way to set different `author` and `description` for both platforms?

Comment: Sure, you can add `preference` and `config-file` elements for the appropriate attributes/properties

Answer (score 0):

Recent Cordova versions have added official support for [`<edit-config>`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config) and [`<config-file>`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#config-file) blocks in the config.xml, so it can be

```
<widget version="1.8.3.2"...>
    ...
    <platform name="ios">
        <edit-config target="CFBundleShortVersionString" file="*-Info.plist" mode="overwrite">
            <string>1.8.32</string>
        </edit-config>
        ...
    </platform>
</widget>
```

without adding plugins.